# Showing "Application Error" while opening Flask app on Heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

This is my first time using Heroku. I have builded a deep learning flask web app. It is running fine on local machine but when i try to open the app it shows "Application error". I have changed the requirements.txt and procfile to see the effect as it was suggested on other community pages but it was not working.

my file structure:

```
ImageClassifier_DeepLearning
 |
 + static
 |      |
 |      + style.css
 |
 + templates
 |       |
 |       + index.html
 |       + index2.html
 |       + show.html
 |       + upload.html
 |
 + uploads
 |       | 
 |       +.jpg,.jpeg ....
 |
 + Procfile
 |
 + requirements.txt
 |
 + app.py
 |
 + model2.h5
```

Procfile

```
  
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:22471 app:app
```

Here, i am attaching my log file.
Thanks a ton if anyone can help!

[image]

Comment: As your logs say 'No module named "main-api" ', you are trying to import a module which does not exist (or does not exist where you think it does). Make sure your Procfile is at the same directory level as your main-api and also make sure there are no typos in your module name. It would help if you showed us your project structure.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your project directory? To know where your file "main-api.py" is located.

Comment: @MurphyAdam  thanks for acknowledging the problem, i have added the file structure in the post.

Comment: @wowkin2 thanks for acknowledging the problem, i have added the file structure in the post.

Comment: @RoopakKrishna please revert change with original command and add **UPD:** if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `main-api:app` to `app:app` in `Procfile` file.

```sh
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:22471 app:app
```

Comment: Thanks, I made changes but now `2020-08-01T14:49:45.838347+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=deeplearning-app-classifier.herokuapp.com request_id=4f50acda-1bf2-4250-a0d2-51af634c980c fwd="223.224.174.195" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https ` getting this!

Comment: @RoopakKrishna On `Resources` tab activate web process.

Comment: previously it was showing a dyno but after i made the change, it got disappear now no process is showing! I am restarting it again and again but no results...

Comment: @RoopakKrishna my fault, you need to add `web: ` at the beginning.

Comment: @RoopakKrishna check if you deployed that. Or try that command without “web:” locally

Comment: thanks for suggestion but no luck so far, lets see...

Comment: I think it is not detecting the Procfile.

Comment: @RoopakKrishna The main problem here was to solve "Application Error". Now you are looking how to solve the issue with `Procfile`. I believe it is another error that should be answered in separate question.